# jquery mobile input text value pass to page 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

im new in jquery mobile so i don't know how to pass the value of my dynamic input text boxes in my page1 to my next page2 when a button is clicked ive seen a sample but there is no command on button submit

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post" action="processForm.php">                    
        <li data-role="fieldcontain"> 
            <label for="children" class="select">Number of Kids</label>
            <select name="children" id="children" data-mini="true">
               <option value="0">0</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
            </select> 
        </li>
            <div id="kidsFields"></div>
    </form>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>

var html = '';
$('#children').on('change', function() {
    children = $(this).val();
    html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        html += '<label>Name</label><input type="text" id="textName' + i + '" name="child' + i + 'Name" /><label>Age</label><input type="text" name="child' + i + 'Age" id="textAge' + i + '" />';
    }

    $('#kidsFields').html(html);
    $('#kidsFields').append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />');

    $('.ui-page').trigger('create');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HwFFU/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id to the submit button:

```
 $('#kidsFields').append('<input id="submitBtn" href="#page2" type="submit" value="Submit" />');
```

add its click event:

```
$("#submitBtn").off('click').on('click', function () {

  // page1 is the id of the data-role page, having input type elements
  var formData =  $("#page1 :input").serializeArray();
  // sessionStorage.setItem("inputValues", JSON.stringify(formData));

});
```

You can save this formData into sessionStorage, which is a string representation of JSON key valued object with each input type and its associated values, to be used in any other pages. When you would get this item, you would need to parse it JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("inputValues"));

Comment: cool let me try this out and il get back on you on my response ty

Comment: its stop stated where to load the data?where should i load it and can you tell me about sessionStorage coz i dont know a thing about it

Comment: is your app a website??? if yes then session storage gets stored in the browser. In the fiddler check by putting alert in submit after var formData : alert(JSON.stringify(formData));. this gets stored in sessionStorage (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: yes it is.the thing is it is still not displaying maybe im doing it wrong

Comment: Check this fiddle it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HwFFU/21/, I have removed php file, but instead of page2 you could have this sessionStorage object retrieved in php form too.

Comment: its working fine for me as well but how can i load input text box in page 2 that was the original question.

Comment: @sheetal how can i revert serialized object

Answer (score 0):

```
On page1 you can store with local storage

use button instead of type="submit"
>> frm is form id
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn_submit" />


$('#btn_submit').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
if(event.handled !== true)
    {  
    localStorage.setItem("formdata",  $('#frm').serialize());
    event.handled = true;
}
return false;
});


On page2 load event get local storage value.

$('#page2').on('pageshow',function(event){
if(event.handled !== true){ 
   localStorage.getItem("formdata");
   event.handled = true;
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: can i ask you one more thing if you serialize it turns to text right?how can i turn it back to like input text again or something like that.did i mention im using internal pages here?